# flush/delete cookie not working after each request

Tags: session, session-cookies

We are getting HTML login page while hitting Site Minder service using SM Session.

We are getting cookie from httprequest by using httprequest.getcookie(). Please provide some suggestion to delete/flush cookie after each request to get a proper JSON response from site minder service.

We tried to flush out the cookie by using maxagelimit but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteCookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

or

```
document.cookie =
      "name=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;path=/";
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**